Custom ToolTip or textbox for wpf chart in c# using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
I am trying to show a textbox when hovering over a datapoint and which will show values of the point. This textbox I need it to be next to the mouse similarly to a tooltip.
I was able to show the value in the tooltip but I want to make a custom textbox with specific Background and Foreground colors that will be displayed with the chart value when mouse hover over datapoint.
using system.windows.controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents; 
using System.Windows.Input; 
using System.Windows.Media;
using System-Windows.Media. Imaging; 
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting:
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization;
String Indicator;
double yValue;
// Peformance Indicator
System Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart vChart = (System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart)this.FindName("Chart_Res"):

List<ChartsData> ChartValues = ChartsData.GetResloution(DateTime.Now.Year);
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series seriesI = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
seriesI.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Doughnut;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
indicator = vChartValues[i].ResIndicator; 
yValue = Double.Parse(vChartValues[i].Res);
seriesI.Points.Add(new DataPoint(yValue, yValue) { LegendText = vChartValues[i].ResIndicator });

foreach (DataPoint point in seriesI.Points)
{
point.Label ="#PERCENT";
point.LabelToolTip = "#VALX: #PERCENT.";
}
vChart.Legends.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend("Legend1"));
vChart.Legends["Legend1"].Enabled = true; 
vChart.Series.Add(seriesI);

I was able to show the value in the tooltip but I want to make a custom textbox with specific Background and Foreground colors that will be displayed with the chart value when mouse hover over datapoint.
